# Objective c decode encrypted data

Tags: objective-c, rest, encryption, hex, encryption-symmetric

I receive a piece of encrypted json from a rest web service call. The following ruby code properly decodes the response back to json. The received data is first base64 decoded, then the first 16 bytes is treated as the iv, and the rest as data. The key is de-hexed (lack of better expression) first.

```
encrypted = Base64.decode64(res) #base 64 decode

de_cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-128-CBC")
de_cipher.decrypt
de_cipher.key = [key].pack('H*') #de-hex the key
de_cipher.iv = encrypted[0..15] # the first 16 bytes is the IV

descrypted = de_cipher.update(encrypted) << de_cipher.final;
json_string = descrypted[16 .. (descrypted.size - 1)] #taking away the first 16, rest is data
```

The ruby code was merely a preparation for me to understand the data. What I really need is to call this web service and decode in objective c on iPhone. But so far there is no luck, and I cannot decrypt the received string to proper json. Below is what I have:

```
//self.responseData is received through NSURLConnection, pretty sure it is piece together correctly. But there is \r\n at the end, which made it not correct length for base64, so I took the last two bytes away.
NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[self.responseData subdataWithRange:(NSRange){0, self.responseData.length - 2}] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSLog(@"tvm get token response = [%@]",str);

//CreateDataWithHexString is something I found on stack overflow, supposed to reverse hex string to binary
NSString * key =[[MyProfile sharedInstance] getOneProperty:TVM_KEY];
//NSData *keyData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:key options:0];
NSData *keyData = [self CreateDataWithHexString:key];

//base64 decode the received string
NSData * whole = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:str options:0];
NSData * iv = [whole subdataWithRange:(NSRange){0, 16}];
NSData * data = [whole subdataWithRange:(NSRange){16, whole.length - 16}];

CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
size_t          cryptBytes = 0;    // Number of bytes moved to buffer.
NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:data.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                   kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                   kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                   keyData.bytes,
                   kCCKeySizeAES128,
                   iv.bytes,
                   data.bytes,
                   data.length,
                   dataOut.mutableBytes,
                   dataOut.length,
                   &cryptBytes);

if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    dataOut.length = cryptBytes;
    NSString * json = [dataOut base64Encoding];
    NSLog(@"json = [%@]", dataOut);
    NSLog(@"json = [%@]", json);
}
else {
```

The key was initially generated as following, hope it makes sense to de-hex as above:

```
CFUUIDRef theKeyUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef keyuuid = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theKeyUUID);
CFRelease(theKeyUUID);
//server side expect a uuid without those -'s.
NSString * key = [(__bridge NSString *)keyuuid stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
CFRelease(keyuuid);
```

Below is CreateDataWithHexString I found on stack overflow, hopefully it is for the right purpose here:

```
-(NSData *)CreateDataWithHexString:(NSString *)inputString
{
NSUInteger inLength = [inputString length];

unichar *inCharacters = alloca(sizeof(unichar) * inLength);
[inputString getCharacters:inCharacters range:NSMakeRange(0, inLength)];

UInt8 *outBytes = malloc(sizeof(UInt8) * ((inLength / 2) + 1));

NSInteger i, o = 0;
UInt8 outByte = 0;
for (i = 0; i < inLength; i++) {
    UInt8 c = inCharacters[i];
    SInt8 value = -1;

    if      (c >= '0' && c <= '9') value =      (c - '0');
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') value = 10 + (c - 'A');
    else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') value = 10 + (c - 'a');

    if (value >= 0) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            outBytes[o++] = (outByte << 4) | value;
            outByte = 0;
        } else {
            outByte = value;
        }

    } else {
        if (o != 0) break;
    }
}

return [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:outBytes length:o freeWhenDone:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up the decryption part was alright, but the display was wrong. It is all because of this one line:

```
NSString * json = [dataOut base64Encoding];
```

I was not looking at the decrypted data, but rather its `Base64` encoded string, obviously it won't look like a valid `JSON`.